# White space inside the subfigure gets adjusted when I try to adjust the space outside the figure

Tags: spacing, subcaption

I am writing an IEEE conference. I have adjusted the white space around single figures without any problem using the command: 
`\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-15pt}`

However, when I tried to use the same in a figure with two subfigures, the end result is not what I expected.

The code I used:

```
\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-15pt}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{111.png}
        \caption{LV distribution}
        \label{fig2a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{111.png}
        \caption{MV distribution}
        \label{fig2b}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Location of DVR.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

the output I got:

[image]

What I tried is to adjust the white space between the caption and the following text. But the code adjusted the spacing between the subfigures too. sub-caption a is missing, sub-caption b is overlapping with the Figure's main caption.

Can someone please advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replacing 111.png with example-image resulted in no space between the subfigures.  Evidently your image has a lot of extra white space, so the best way to get rid of it is to crop the image with \includegraphics.

Comment: @JohnKormylo hey thanks for your reply. I am fine with the picture sizing. When I adjust the white space after the main caption, it adjusts my subcaptions too. You can see an overlap. Any advise to avoid that would be helpful

Comment: IEEE will not appreciate messing with \belowcaptionskip.  While getting [trim=...] to work the first time will take some effort, it really is the best solution.  If the white space is on top, it will cover up the preceding caption.

Comment: @JohnKormylo These are all sample pictures. The real pictures don't have white area around. it is cropped. That's why I thought I am doing something wrong with the code to adjust the spacing.

Comment: So why the negative \belowcaptionskip?  It defaults to 0pt.  I like to add extra space between rows of subfigures so that the subfigure captions are closer to their images than the ones below (but not between the subfigure and final caption).